# Evaluate Traces in Evalvid

Tags: mp4, mp4box

I am using evalvid 2.7, ns-2.35, ubuntu 14.04 to evaluate video traffic. 
But when i use this command:

`~/myevalvid2$ ./etmp4 -f -0 sd_a01 rd_a01 st_a01 a01.mp4 a01out`

i receive this with an error at the end:

> loss_a01out.txt: percentage of lost frames|packets
>   column 1: I (including H)
>   column 2: P
>   column 3: B
>   column 4: overall
>
> delay_a01out.txt: jitter/delay statistics
>   column 1: frame|packet id
>   column 2: loss flag
>   column 3: end-to-end delay s
>   column 4: sender inter frame|packet lag s
>   column 5: receiver inter [frame|packet] lag s
>   column 6: cumulative jitter s Hartanto et. al.
>
> rate_s_a01out.txt: sender rate
>   column 1: time s
>   column 2: momentary rate bytes/s
>   column 3: cumulative rate bytes/s
>
> rate_r_a01out.txt: receiver rate
>   column 1: time s
>   column 2: momentary rate bytes/s 
>   column 3: cumulative rate bytes/s
>
> Error in etmp4: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x085ec028
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export MALLOC_CHECK_=0

run the above command on the terminal and then run etmp4 command